# Создайте функцию, которая принимает слово и возвращает новое слово без включения первого символа

Tags: javascript

```
    function firstWord(text) {
  let firstBlank = text.indexOf('');
  if (firstBlank == -1) { 
    return text;
  } 
  return text.slice(0, firstBlank);
}
```

Такой код получился но я так и не понял как написать функцию которая будет отрезать первую букву слова

Comment: Вместо 0 написать 1

Comment: `let firstBlank = text.indexOf('');` вот это точно не нужно. Проще и правильнее проверять на длину.

Comment: Большое спасибо  за ответ, но так и непонятно так как же сделать правильно

Comment: Например `if (firstBlank &&firstBlank.length > 1) {` то делайте *slice(**1**...* иначе возвращайте text

Comment: ну все манипуляции с firstBlank вообще не ясны, что это и зачем. если по условию этого не надо..... а отрезать первый символ - нужно 1 вместо 0 ..... причём второй аргумент даже уже не нужен

Answer (score 0):

```js
function firstWord(text) {
  return text.slice(1);
}

console.log(firstWord('Text')); // 'est'
console.log(firstWord('T')); // ''
console.log(firstWord('')); // ''
```